# Any way to convert this for loop with list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, list-comprehension

The reason I am asking is that in incorporates various data structures, dict, list, string.

```
bffer = ""
dict_size = 128
for character in string:
    appnd_bffer = bffer + character
    if appnd_bffer in codebook:
        bffer = appnd_bffer
    else:
        output_list.append(codebook[bffer])
        codebook[appnd_bffer] = dict_size
        dict_size += 1
        bffer = character
```

I am new to list comprehensions so I could really use an explanation if it is possible. Cheers.

Comment: Why do you need this to be converted to a list comprehension? That'd really hurt readability.

Comment: Why would you want to? If, by some diabolical voodoo, it were possible to jam all that into a list comprehension, it would be utterly unreadable.

Comment: `[do_everything_youre_doing_in_the_loop(character) for character in string]`…? This is too much code to inline into a comprehension…

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Just curious if its possible, just starting with python and would like to know the limits :)

Comment: [Don't be clever.](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/why-is-cleverness-considered-harmful-in-programming-by-some-people/25281)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus It's not _utterly_ unreadable, but it's certainly not pretty. :) OTOH, I guess I cheated a little by moving the bulk of the work into a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to give you an idea of why it's a **really** bad idea to try and stuff your LZW compressor's loop into a list comprehension, I've actually gone ahead and written some crazy code that does just that.

It uses some rather dodgy tricks, and it won't work on Python 3 because in Python 3 a list comprehension runs in its own scope; in Python 2 a list comprehension runs in the scope of the surrounding code. And that means my trick of passing the original buffer into the the list comp won't work in Python 3.

Firstly, here's your original code wrapped in a function, with a couple of variable name changes, and a few added extras to make it a runnable, testable example.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def lzw_compress_Boa(data):
    dict_size = 128
    codebook = {chr(i): i for i in range(dict_size)}

    output_list = []
    oldbuff = ""
    for ch in data:
        newbuff = oldbuff + ch
        if newbuff in codebook:
            oldbuff = newbuff
        else:
            output_list.append(codebook[oldbuff])
            codebook[newbuff] = dict_size
            dict_size += 1
            oldbuff = ch
    return output_list

data = 'this data is this data'

output_list = lzw_compress_Boa(data)
print(output_list)
print(len(data), '->', len(output_list))
```

**output**

```
[116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 100, 97, 116, 97, 32, 130, 32, 128, 138, 133]
22 -> 15
```

We don't actually need to keep the codebook's size in a separate variable. Like all of Python's built-in container types, a dict keeps track of its size, and we can use the `len()` function to get it. So we can replace these 2 lines:

```
codebook[newbuff] = dict_size
dict_size += 1
```

with this line:

```
codebook[newbuff] = len(codebook)
```

---

Now here's the crazy version that uses a list comprehension. Remember kids, *please* **don't** try this at home! :)

```
def lzw_compress_crazy(data):
    dict_size = 128
    codebook = {chr(i): i for i in range(dict_size)}

    def magic(oldbuff, ch):
        newbuff = oldbuff + ch
        if newbuff in codebook:
            return [(newbuff, None)]
        else:
            codebook[newbuff] = len(codebook)
            return [(ch, codebook[oldbuff])]

    oldbuff = ""
    return [result for ch in data
        for oldbuff, result in magic(oldbuff, ch) if result]
```

Note that this version is not only harder to read than the first one I posted, it's also less efficient. And as I said at the start, it's less portable, and it uses some totally dodgy tricks that should never be used in serious code.

List comprehensions are cool, and once you're used to them they can make your code more concise, which can aid in readability, as long as you don't try to do too much in them. A list comp is *slightly* more efficient than equivalent code using `.append` in a "traditional" style `for` loop, but they aren't magic, and using an incomprehensible list comprehension instead of a a nice clear readable traditional `for` loop is **not** Pythonic.

Comment: Lazy. I want to see `[b for b in Popen(['working_c_implementation'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate(data)[0]]`.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus LOL. I _was_ going to maintain the state in an iterable class, but decided not to go too crazy. :)

Answer (score 8):

The loop currently depends on being able to assign to `bffer`. Because assignment is a *statement*, and list comprehensions only can contain *expressions*, converting this to a list comprehension would require a lot of hard-to-follow trickery with mutable objects.

As such, converting this to a list comprehension would result in an unreadable mess, without any clear benefits (any speed benefits from removing the `list.append()` call will be offset by the mutable object manipulations).

Comment: Has anyone done the obvious pun about *incomprehensibility* yet…?

Comment: @deceze: I was trying to avoid it! :-D

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way I could see a comprehensive example? I didn't think this was possible

Comment: @Noah I'm out of time right now but here you can use `collections.count()` to replace `dict_count`, and use a dict for the variables (using `dict.__setitem__` or `dict.update` to set values in it).

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be made into a list comprehension because it contains expressions other than the ones that make up the list (e.g. `dict_size += 1`). Those expressions just have no place to go in a list comprehension, since the only purpose of a comprehension is to create that object. What might help you is to create a separate function containing the logic for a single iteration of the loop, then use that function in a loop.

Comment: It can still be done. It won't be readable however. The `dict_size` value could be handled by a `itertools.count()` object, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Quick question, would adding a function and doing what you said be a positive change to the code? Either in terms of readability/"cleanliness"?

Comment: @Boa Yes, it's usually good practice but generally depends on your specific situation

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW, the OP's code performs LZW compression, the `dict_size` counter is redundant: it can be read directly from `len(codebook)`.